# FirebaseIOS: Use of Undeclared Type 'DatabaseReference'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry for the weird question

Yesterday I had to update my firebase pod, before that everything was fine, but after that, I can't retrieve data anymore

So here's my code

```
    //  let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    var rsef: DatabaseReference! // undeclared

    rsef = Database.database().reference() //. undeclared
```

I read the official firebase setup instructions, those are right, but I don't know why it says undeclared

For reference, here's my full code

```
 ref.child("KurdishRsta").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId().queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with:
        { (snapshot) in
            print("Database\(String(describing: snapshot.value))")
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let FullRsta1 = value?["Rsta"]
        let FullMeaning1 = value?["Meaning"]





        self.RetrivedRsta.insert(RstasFromFirebase(FullRsta:FullRsta1 as! String ,FullMeaning : FullMeaning1 as! String), at: 0)

        self.tableview.reloadData()



    })
}
```

the podfile

```
    Target 'Dictionary' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!
   pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Auth'
   pod 'Firebase/Storage'
   pod 'Firebase/Database'

  # Pods for Dictionary
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'SKSplashView'
pod "FGTranslator"
pod 'SCLAlertView-Objective-C'
pod 'OneSignal'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'ChameleonFramework'
pod 'QMChatViewController'
pod 'ApiAI'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod "ZHPopupView"
pod 'FCAlertView'
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
pod "CZPicker"
pod 'DTTJailbreakDetection'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
```

Comment: Can you post your podfile and the import of Firebase in your code please ?

Comment: @GabrielDiez ofcourse, i've edited my post

Comment: What happens when you run ‘pod outdated’ from the command line?  Maybe for some reason it’s pulling an older dependency if it’s in the Podfile.lock file. Actually another way you could check is if you replace ‘DatabaseReference’ with ‘FIRDatabaseReference’ and if that works, it pulled the outdated pod for some reason.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Be sure to add an import of firebase database in the file you call DatabaseReference and not just import Firebase alone

```
 import FirebaseDatabase
```

Comment: The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start) doesn't mention importing FirebaseDatabase. Your solution does seem to work for me though!

Comment: Google should just make up their mind about what each framework contains once and for all. They keep changing this from one version to another...  Docs are outdated.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift Version 5, Firebase (6.5.0), FirebaseAnalytics (6.0.4), FirebaseDatabase (6.0.0)**

Follow steps on the [Google's Page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#top_of_page)

Earlier use of `import FirebaseDatabase` has been removed.
Use only `import Firebase` in a *Swift* file and to use a database reference a variable can be used as `var firebaseDatabaseRef: DatabaseReference!`

If the issue persist please try to *clean and build* a project couple of times or use following commands from the terminal and try to *clean and build* again.

```
$pod deintegrate
```

and then

```
$pod install
```

**Podfile**:

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

Answer (score 3):

if it worked before then it must be the pod file, here is mine for reference.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
target 'MyAwesomeApp' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use 
dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyAwesomeApp

  target 'MyAwesomeAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAwesomeAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: thanks, neither i dont think its the podfile, i guess its firebase' is it working on your side?

Comment: The error you're getting suggests a dependency or scoping issue. Very unlikely that its related to your code. If you email me the file in question I might have a better chance at solving your issue. I have to add the good ol' "have you restarted your computer" question too, apple products are far buggier than people like to admit.

Comment: pod 'Firebase/Database' is the key

Answer (score 1):

In my case, git was ignoring `Pods` directory so pretty much every time I changed branch I had to run `pod install` command (minor changes on the configurations).

In one of those changes I started getting this error. I tried cleaning build folder, delivery data folder, restart, and none worked until I delete the content of Pods directory and run `pod install`.